# Are there d3.js best practises for custom selections?

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3.js. I understand that I can select a whole group of nodes with `selectAll`, e.g. `node = svg.selectAll(".node")` and call methods on all of them.

However, if I don't want the methods to be applied to all nodes, but e.g. to all except one node, how would I best do that?

Do `selectAll` on another subset defined by e.g. another class?

Or more generally put: Given d3.js specific selection approach, what is the idiom for selecting different subsets of nodes? Define a class for every subset and select based on that class? I wonder if in such a scenario a `for` loop over all nodes with `if`s selecting subsets would be a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain `selectAll()` like that :

```
d3.selectAll("tr").selectAll("td");
```

(see https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/)

Or you can use `filter()` to remove some elements

(see https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#filter)

Or you can exclude one element like that

```
  d3.selectAll('.node:not(#idToExclude)').remove()
```

(see this example https://jsfiddle.net/oxj78cfv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax to select a specific node based on it's id :

```
select = d3.select('#nodeID')
```

Comment: For one node it's easy. But what if I want to select all nodes except this one? Or more generally put: Given d3.js specific selection approach, what is the idiom for selecting different subsets of nodes?

Comment: You need to have something that differentiates the nodes you want to select and the others that you don't want to select. You can do that with an attribute based on a function, for example you can add a class, filled with the values of your datasets : `svg.selectAll("path").attr('class', function(d) {return "d" + d.properties.id;});` Then you use the code of my previous answer to select only the ids you want and not the others. For the syntax you can read this to understand how the selections work with d3 : https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections

Answer (score 0):

If your elements have a specific class or ID, you can use the `:not()` selector.

For instance, in this fiddle, I created a bunch of circles, with 5 different classes, going from `class0` to `class4`. This will select all the circles that are not `class2` and make them transparent when you click the button:

```
svg.selectAll("*:not(.class2)").attr("opacity", 0);
```

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/wzfmzeqz/3/

If the one element you want to avoid have a given ID (IDs are unique), you can write:

```
svg.selectAll("*:not(#foo)")
```

Here is the documentation about the *negation pseudo-class*: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation

Comment: I chose Tim B's similar answer as the right one because he was first. Thanks!